# Reading data in a SpreadsheetDocument from MemoryStream

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a page on my site where a user can upload a XLSX spreadsheet. This is a .NET Core web application using the DocumentFormat.OpenXml (2.15.0) NuGet package.

I'm trying to read through each row in the spreadsheet they upload and do something with that data. I'm trying to do this without saving a physical file by copying the file to a MemoryStream, then reading the file from that stream, but not sure if that's possible.

The problem is that when reading the doc from the stream, it's like there's no data in the spreadsheet

Here's what I have:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await viewModel.SpreadsheetFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // confirm that copying to memory stream worked correctly
    var fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbook = document.WorkbookPart;
        WorksheetPart worksheet = workbook.WorksheetParts.First();

        SheetData sheetData = worksheet.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
        string text;

        // no rows, doesn't enumerate here
        foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
        {
            foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                text = c.CellValue.Text;
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added a couple lines to read bytes from the memory stream just to confirm that it's working, which it is.

But when I try to create a SpreadsheetDocument from the memory stream and read the sheet data, it's just empty, it doesn't enumerate through the rows.

The code to read the sheet data I got from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet

Is this possible, or am I just doing this wrong?

Comment: After writing into a stream, the position would be at the end. You need to seek back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set memory stream to zero after reading to it. Change code to this:

```
await viewModel.SpreadsheetFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```